# Why new and delete so slow in a loop under MSVC 2010

Tags: c++, new-operator, delete-operator

I got a problem when I tried to create and delete an instance of the class in a loop.
Execution time of iterations is quite different. As I understand it, this is associated with the removal of objects from memory. However, the behavior of this operation I do not understand. Why time is different? How do I fix it? Time is steady when I'm deleting the object in a separate thread.

```
class NODE{

    public:
        NODE(){}

        NODE* add(NODE* node)
        {
            children.push_back(node);
            return node;
        }

        virtual ~NODE()
        {
            for(vector<NODE*>::iterator it = children.begin(); it != children.end(); ++it)
            {
                delete *it;
            }
        }

        vector<NODE*> children;

};

NODE* create()
{
    NODE* node( new NODE() );

    for (int i=0; i<200;i++) {
        NODE* subnode = node->add( new NODE());
        for (int k=0; k<20; k++) subnode->add( new NODE());
    }

    return node;
}

int main()
{
    NODE* root;
    unsigned t;

    for (int i=0; i<30; i++){
        t = clock();
        cout << "Create... ";
        root = create();
        delete root;
        cout<< clock()-t << endl;
    }
}
```

ADDED:
I'm confused. When I run program out of VS it works fine...

Comment: Dynamic allocation is slow, mmkay?

Comment: Also, you're creating 120,000 node items.  You run create 30 times, each create makes a 200 sub nodes, that's 6,000 objects, and then each subnode creates 20 more nodes, that's 120,000 items.

Comment: For reference, related (and almost duplicate) question from same user: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713329/why-does-it-look-like-boostshared-ptr-constructions-are-getting-slower

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to what other answers say you have to account for Visual C++ 10 runtime heap being thread-safe. This implies that even when you only have one thread you encounter some overhead facilitating heap operations being thread-safe. So one reason you see such poor results is that you use a universal but rather slow heap implementation.

The reason why you get different timing with/without the debugger is [a special heap is used when a program is started under debugger (even in Release configuration)](http://mackeblog.blogspot.com/2009/02/disabling-visual-studios-debugger-heap.html) and that special heap is also relatively slow.

Answer (score 5):

When you create an object, sometimes a new block of memory for it will be allocated, and sometimes it will fit into an already-existing block. This will cause two allocations to potentially take differing amounts of time.

If you want to make the time allocations and frees take consistent, handle them inside your application - grab a big chunk of memory and service allocations from that block. Of course, when you need another chunk, the allocation that causes that to happen is going to take longer... But with large chunks it should happen infrequently.

The only way to make allocations and deallocations take a perfectly consistent amount of time would be to slow down the fast ones until they take the maximum amount of time any request could spend. This would be the Harrison Bergeron approach to performance optimization. I don't recommend it.

Comment: Why time is steady when I'm deleting the object in a separate thread.

Answer (score 1):

There are real-time heaps in existance, but generally memory heap operations (dynamic allocations and deallocations) are the cannoical example of a [non-deterministic operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_algorithm). This means that the runtime varies, and doesn't even have a very good bound.

The issue is that you generally need adjacent blocks of memory merged into a single block when they occur. If that isn't done, eventually you'll just have oodles of tiny blocks and a large allocation may fail even though there really is plenty of memory available for it. On any given call there may or may not be merging to do, and the amount to do may vary. It all depends on the pattern of allocations/deallocations your system has performed recently, which is not something you can plan for at all. So we call it "non-deterministic".

If you don't like this behavior, there are really two possibilities:

1. Switch to using a real-time heap. Your OS probably doesn't have one built in, so you'd have to go buy or download one and use it for all your memory operations. One I've used in the past is [TLSF](http://rtportal.upv.es/rtmalloc/).
2. Don't perform dynamic memory allocation/deallocation in your main loop (IOW: not after initialization). This is how we realtime programmers have trained ourselves to code for ages.

Comment: the loop is just example. I have not it in real code. But why difference is so MUCH?

Comment: @user713782 - Again, it all depends on the pattern of allocations/deallocations, and how much work your system's heap has to get everything merged together the way it wants it. What exactly causes it the most work depends on the algorithm used.

Comment: Ok. But it explain that time is not increased when dealocations use in separate thread too?

Comment: @user713782 - Why would it be? Generally all threads in a process use the same heap.

Answer (score 0):

Generally it's not possible to predict memory allocation/deallocation times. For example times may vary significantly if the user space heap runs out of pages and needs to request more from the kernel and later when accessing a newly allocated page triggers a page fault.

So even if you go forward and implement your own heap using big chunks of memory, your allocation times will vary because lazyness is in the nature of the underlying memory system.

Comment: Allocating the pages locked into main RAM via `mlock` is sufficient to guard against lazy allocations. All the overheads would be incurred when the chunk is allocated rather than later.

Comment: I understand that, but the difference of time in the example can be x * 10. And if I do not use delete, new object will be created in the new block of memory and time will be not increased. Why it happens?

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanna know why its slow you need to run a real profiler on it, such as AMD's [codeanalyst](http://developer.amd.com/cpu/CodeAnalyst/codeanalystwindows/Pages/default.aspx), `clock` isn't exactly a high presision timer.

The reason why it'll run different each time depends on the paging of the underlying system, the CPU load and whether your data has been cached by the processor.